# Formula to add multiple values depending on picklist value

Tags: formula, formula-field

What could a formula look like to add multiple values depending on a picklist field's value such that the formula field's data gets separated by a ';'? 
I know how to display a single value in formula field depending on picklist value (using Case) but not sure of multiple data. The data should look like below:

**Picklist field**   Beverages
**Formula field**    Tea; Coffee; Mocktails

**Picklist field**   Food
**Formula field**    Lasagna; Pasta; Tacos

**Picklist field**       Desert
**Formula field**    Banana Split; Brownie

Please help

Comment: The values in multiselect picklist are by default separated by ";" in the backend. So I think simple formula should work.

Comment: I'm using a picklist field and need to create a formula field which updates with multiple values depending on picklist field's value.

Comment: Is it that what you want to have a formula field returning picklist (multiple values)? This is not possible. You have to have another field as picklist and then you can set a dependency for it to be controlled by your original picklist values.

Comment: @Oleksiy Thanks for the info. But if I create dependent picklist, how will it automatically update with the multiple values as I do not want to manually add the multiple values but they should automatically update as I select say 'Food' from original picklist